# findstr giving incorrect errorlevel

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr, errorlevel

Why does this:

```
for /f "tokens=5 delims=<>" %%G in ('findstr /C:"<a href=\"register\">" "index.html"') do echo %%G
```

give an errorlevel 1 while this

```
findstr /C:"<a href=\"register\">" "index.html"
```

gives an errorlevel 0?

The first code gives me the string I'm looking for. The second one gives the line of text where the string is in. I need the first code to give me an errorlevel 0 because it returned no errors as far as I know. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps if you were to post a relevant portion of your file, others could repeat your experience without makig assumptions?

Comment: `<th style="width:36%"><a href="register"><em>Premium</em></a></th>` I'm looking for the word "Premium" in the first code, and that's what it gave.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` command can *not* set the ERRORLEVEL to 1; it just preserve the same value it had before. I suggest you to set the ERRORLEVEL to 0 before the `for` via this line:

```
ver > nul
```

You may review a full description of the ERRORLEVEL values set by all internal commands at [What are the ERRORLEVEL values set by internal cmd.exe commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/what-are-the-errorlevel-values-set-by-internal-cmd-exe-commands)

Also, you didn't said us *how* you are testing the ERRORLEVEL. If you are using `if %ERRORLEVEL% ...` and this command is placed inside a code block, it may also be a Delayed Expansion related problem.

Comment: Please, tell us the cause! Specially if it is _not_ one of the ones mentioned: previous errorlevel=1 or delayed expansion problem...

Comment: So the solution is to set the errorlevel to 0 before the `for` command as I indicated in my answer, right? In my opinion my answer gives the correct solution, so you should mark it as the right answer...