# How to get windows returncode withi a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, return-code

I have some perl scripts which are invoked by a windows batch. The perl scripts provide returncodes which i need to output, but i alwas get 0.
Even with a absolute reduced perl script:

```
use Modern::Perl '2015';

exit 1;
```

I get 0 als ERRORLEVEL.
Here's the part of my windows batch file, where i invoke the perl script:

```
cmd /c "C:\Strawberry32\portableshell.bat C:\Users\abc\error.pl"
echo ERRORLEVEL Error Script: %ERRORLEVEL%
```

The output is "ERRORLEVEL Error Script: 0"

I already tried "start /wait ..." insted of cmd, but here i see a second console window, which i have to close manualy. That's not what i want.

If i enter "C:\Strawberry32\portableshell.bat C:\Users\abc\error.pl" manually in a konsole window, i see/get the expected Errorlevel 1, what's wrong here?

Comment: what about `call C:\Strawberry32\portableshell.bat C:\Users\abc\error.pl`

Comment: great, this works the way i want it to do

Answer (score 0):

Several points here. First of all, you have not shown us the code where you "invoke the perl script", but the code where you invoke `portableshell.bat` file, and you did not show us the contents of such *Batch file*. So the first and simplest way to solve your problem is:

**1-** Insert in your windows Batch file *the same command* you use to "invoke the perl script" in the `C:\Strawberry32\portableshell.bat` file. This will give access to the errorlevel from the perl script for sure.

I assume that the contents of `portableshell.bat` file are basically two lines: the one that run the perl script followed by this line:

```
exit /B %errorlevel%
```

The purpose of previous line is to return the errorlevel from the perl script to the Batch file that *called* this one Batch file. This mechanism works perfectly as long as *this Batch file be called via* `call` *command*:

**2-** Invoke the `C:\Strawberry32\portableshell.bat` file via a `call` command:

```
call C:\Strawberry32\portableshell.bat C:\Users\abc\error.pl
```

If the `portableshell.bat` file is invoked via `cmd /c` instead of `call`, then you must set the returning errorlevel *of cmd.exe program* via a plain `exit` command, with NO `/B` switch:

**3-** Invoke the `C:\Strawberry32\portableshell.bat` file via `cmd /c` line, but terminate it with this command:

```
exit %errorlevel%
```

You may read a further explanation of the errorlevel stuff and the differences of `exit /B number` vs `exit number` at [What are the ERRORLEVEL values set by internal cmd.exe commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/what-are-the-errorlevel-values-set-by-internal-cmd-exe-commands). At that site you may read that a `start /B /WAIT portableshell.bat` command may also be used to solve this problem, but this method also requires to end the .bat file with `exit %errorlevel%` in the same way as the `cmd /c` method.