# Get Return Value from Console Application in Batch file

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, console-application

I'm trying to get return value from console application in batch file. Console application keep returns 0 value even when the rtnValue is 1 in console application

## Console Application Code

```
Public Function Main() As Integer
 Dim rtnValue as Int16 = 0

  if Not Process Then rtnValue = 1

  Return rtnValue

End Function
```

## Batch File

```
@ECHO OFF 

start /d "%~dp0" ConsoleApp.exe

if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" goto success

:success
echo Success with error code: %ERRORLEVEL%
PAUSE
goto end

:error
echo Failed with error code: %ERRORLEVEL%
PAUSE

:end
```

Comment: The `START` command does _not_ return the value of the executed command (it return 9059 if the command does not exist). You may use `START /WAIT` or entirely eliminate the START command. Further details in the **Table 4** of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/what-are-the-errorlevel-values-set-by-internal-cmd-exe-commands/34987886#34987886)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `start /d "%~dp0" ConsoleApp.exe` that is launching a new shell to run it in. Instead just use

```
cd %~dp0
ConsoleApp.exe
```

and then test for the exit code.

Comment: When i replace start /d "%~dp0" ConsoleApp.exe with cd %~dp0 ConsoleApp.exe it gets "The Sytem cannot find the path specified"
Success with error code: 1

Comment: A few issues there. I'm not sure why the first line is failing just yet. The "Success with error code" message is because you need to do a `goto error ` not `goto success`

Comment: What does your batch file echo when it runs that `cd %~dp0`. It should be the directory of the batch file itself,  which should always exist.

Comment: i know why first line failed as  cd %~dp0 and ConsoleApp.exe must be separated into different line. I got the correct result now. Thanks for both of your help ^^