# How to get return/exit code of a batch file started with START command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to run a batch file with `start /high` and still get the return/exit code, i.e. `%ERRORLEVEL%`. The problem seems to be that command **START** does not return the exit code that the batch file returns.

We have a simple batch file for testing named `BatFileThatReturnsOne.bat`.

The contents of `BatFileThatReturnsOne.bat` are

```
EXIT /B 1
```

We are calling this as such:

```
start /high /wait BatFileThatReturnsOne.bat
```

But no matter what the batch file returns, the execution of `start` never has a `%ERRORLEVEL%` of anything other than 0 (zero).

This is all actually called by cfn-init in CloudFormation, but that is probably not relevant because we can reproduce it from a command line window.

The actual call is:

```
cmd.exe /C start /high /wait BatFileThatReturnsOne.bat
```

How do I get `start` to set the `%ERRORLEVEL%` to something other than 0 (zero)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

directly from a `cmd` window or a batch file you can use

```
start /high /wait cmd /c BatFileThatReturnsOne.bat
```

but if you need to start the `cmd` instance to execute the start command that launchs the batch file then you can use

```
cmd /v /e /c" start /high /wait cmd /c launched.cmd & exit ^!errorlevel^!"
```

Comment: Because the cmd is actually being executed from cfn-init in AWS CloudFormation, the 2nd proposed solution worked great.  Thanks, I would have never figured that out!

Answer (score 3):

Just change `EXIT /B 1` by `EXIT 1`.

As explained in the **Table 4** given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34987886/778560) about `START /WAIT bat` command:

```
When the started Batch file ends, set ERRORLEVEL = value from 'EXIT number' commmand.
```

Comment: Thanks.  The problem was actually a little more complicated than the simple bat file (I just created it to test it).  It's actually calling chef-client, which in turn is calling ruby.exe.  Neither of those actually have the "EXIT /B 1", so MC ND's solution ended up working well.

Comment: I am confused by your comment. My answer solves the problem _as stated in the question_. How an answer can solve a problem that is _not_ described in the question? (answer: just by chance) **`:(`**