# Not creating a empty file if there is no output from the for loop in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Hi Am actually trying to redirect the output of a for loop to a file in batch and I don't want to create a empty file if there is no output from the for loop.
In the below code, I am trying to redirect the name and date modified of files in a particular directory which are more than 60 mins old to a file called Errorfiles.txt. If there are no files that were modified in the last 60 mins then I should not get a empty file but am getting a file of 0KB size. Is there anyway I can stop generating that file if there's no output from the for loop ?
Any help would be appreciated Thanks!
-----------------------------------------------------------MAIN.bat-----------------------------------------------------------

```
    @Echo off
    @setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    CALL function.bat %TIME%,CurrentTime

    (for /f "tokens=2,4" %%A in ('dir c:\Users\Administrator
    \Batch\*.* ^| find "/"') do (
    CALL function.bat %%A,FileTime
    REM echo !CurrentTime! !FileTime!
    set /a diff=!CurrentTime!-!FileTime!  
    if !diff! geq 60 (
    echo Filename: %%B Date Modified %%A 
    )
    )) 1>ErrorFiles.txt 2>nul
```

-------------------------------------------------------------------Function.bat--------------------------------------------

```
    @Echo off

    SET time1=%1
    set HH=%time1:~0,2%
    set MM=%time1:~3,2%
    set /a MM=%MM%
    set /a HH=%HH% * 60
    set /a ctime=%HH% + %MM%
    set /a "%~2=%ctime%"
    EXIT /B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method shown below is the simplest and fastest way to test if a `for /F` command generate no output, so delete the empty output file in such a case:

```
(for /F %%A in ('a command') do echo %%A) > output.txt || rem
if errorlevel 1 del output.txt
```

An extensive explanation of this method is given at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34987886/778560), below **Exit Code management**.

Note: the redirection of a command output to a file (and the creation of an empty file) happens *before* the command is executed, so there is no way to know in advance if such an output will be empty...

Answer (score 2):

Compare the following two lines. `a.txt` gets generated, `b.txt` not.

```
(for /f %a in ('REM') do echo %a) >a.txt
for /f %a in ('REM') do (echo %a >b.txt)
```

If you want to keep the speed of redirecting only once (with possibly big files, just delete the file, if it's empty:

```
for %%a in (a.txt) do if %%~za == 0 del %%a
```

Comment: The delete file thing is good man ... Is there any other way to redirect only if it has output ?

Comment: I'm only aware of the method used with `b.bat` The trick there is, the command after `do` is only executed, when there is output from the  `for /f` loop. Downside is, you loose speed (you'll not notice it with small outputs, but can sum up if you have hundrets or thousands of lines of output) Note: you then surely want `>>` instead of `>`