# How to save user input from CHOICE command to a variable to be used later in the errorlevel

Tags: batch-file, dynamic, batch-choice

I have a dynamic list of choices for a program I'm writing. I have it working correctly so that it will change the `CHOICE` options based on the `count` variable but now I'm struggling with making the `errorlevel` dynamic as well. Here is my code:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
@ECHO off
SET count=7
SET ph=
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%count%) DO (
SET ph=!ph!%%a
ECHO !ph!
)
CHOICE /C Q%ph%
IF errorlevel (I don't have a variable for this) (
echo "in if" & pause
)

IF errorlevel 1 echo "out of if" & pause
```

My idea is to set the errorlevel equal to what the user put in (e.g. the user puts in 7 as their choice, the errorlevel becomes 7) The reason I want to do this is because I need the `errorlevel` to pass for everything besides 1, which is reserved for a quit option (which is why I have the "Q" there) Any advice and suggestions are much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Following commands could reset the errorlevel, so save it `Set "MyChoice=%Errorlevel%"` See dynamic environment variables at the end of  `set /?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest following batch code for this task:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
SET count=7
SET ph=
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%count%) DO SET ph=!ph!%%a
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C Q%ph%
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 2 ECHO Bye^^!& GOTO :EOF
SET /A UserChoice=%ERRORLEVEL%-1
ECHO You have chosen %UserChoice%.
PAUSE
```

`IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 2` means if the exit code of **CHOICE** is NOT GREATER OR EQUAL 2 which is the same as if LESS THAN 2 then execute **ECHO** and **GOTO** to exit processing of this batch file.

The command **IF** does not modify value of `ERRORLEVEL` as documented at
[What are the ERRORLEVEL values set by internal cmd.exe commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/)

It would be also possible to first assign the exit code of **CHOICE** to an environment variable decremented by 1 and then make the comparison for quit by comparing the value with `0`.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
SET count=7
SET ph=
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%count%) DO SET ph=!ph!%%a
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C Q%ph%
SET /A UserChoice=%ERRORLEVEL%-1
IF %UserChoice% == 0 ECHO Bye^^!& GOTO :EOF
ECHO You have chosen %UserChoice%.
PAUSE
```

It is not advisable to use an environment variable with name `choice` as it makes it difficult to search for this environment variable in a batch file containing also external command **CHOICE** which is the reason for using `UserChoice`.

The command **CHOICE** is specified with full qualified file name (file path + file name + file extension) for safety reasons. Windows command processor does not need to search for `choice.*` with a file extension listed in environment variable `PATHEXT` in current directory and the directories listed in **local** environment variable `PATH` on using full qualified file name. This makes the batch file robust against corrupted **system** `PATH` containing the path of a folder before most important folder path `%SystemRoot%\System32` which by chance contains also a `choice.*` file with a file extension listed in `PATHEXT`. The **local** environment variable `PATH` does not need to exist at all on running this batch file because of using full qualified file name of executable **CHOICE**. It also does not matter with full qualified file name if a user created a batch file with name `choice.bat` or `choice.cmd` in the directory being the current directory on running this batch file or any other directory in `PATH` being searched by `cmd.exe` before `%SystemRoot%\System32`.

Answer (score 2):

To solve my issue I used the `NEQ` and `EQU` statements that I was not aware would work with `errorlevel`. I also incorporated the suggestion of @LotPings to get this code as a result which works great! To technically save the user input as a variable, I just subtracted one from the choice variable and it equals the same.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
REM @ECHO off
SET count=7
SET ph=
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%count%) DO (
SET ph=!ph!%%a
REM ECHO !ph!
)
CHOICE /C Q%ph%
set choice=%errorlevel%
ECHO %choice%
IF %choice% NEQ 1 ( 
ECHO "not equal" & PAUSE
SET /A choice=choice-1
ECHO !choice! REM This is now the value the user inputted.
PAUSE
)
IF %choice% EQU 1 ECHO "equal" & PAUSE
```