# How do `call` and `exit` commands interplay in batch files in Windows?

Tags: batch-file

I have 2 files `a.bat` and `b.bat`

The `b.bat` file looks like this:

```
exit /b 0
```

The `a.bat` file looks like this

```
call b.bat
```

Question: what effect does execution of `exit /b 0` in `b.bat` have to `a.bat` file which does `call b.bat` assuming we run `a.bat`?

Comment: What did you deduce by yourself when you tried it? Also your question would be better suited to [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/ask).

Comment: The effect of executing `exit /b 0` is explained in the help screen of `exit` command. You may read it entering `exit /?`

Comment: @Aacini question about how is `call` and `exit` work **together**, not each of them alone which can be read about in helps

Comment: Maybe you can glean something from this question: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts)

Comment: `call b.bat` command executed in `a.bat` file causes that when `b.bat` ends, the execution returns to `a.bat`. Period. `exit /b 0` command executed in `b.bat` sets `%errorlevel%` to zero and ends `b.bat`. Period. After that, the `%errorlevel%` value in `a.bat` is zero. Perhaps you may want to read the values of **Table 4** at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/what-are-the-errorlevel-values-set-by-internal-cmd-exe-commands/34987886#34987886)