# Conditional execution behind `set VAR 2> nul` fails

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The [`set` command](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) with a variable name (prefix) sets the [exit code](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) to a non-zero value in case there is no matching variable defined; the exit code can be queried by [conditional execution operators](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

```cmd
set VAR && echo Yes. || echo No!!
```

The above would return `Yes.` if `VAR` (or `VARiable`, etc.) is defined, and `No!!` otherwise, together with the error message `Environment variable VAR  not defined` from the `set` command.

However, when I try to suppress the error message, `No!!` is always echoed, independent on whether or not `VAR` is defined:

```cmd
set VAR 2> nul && echo Yes. || echo No!!
```

The outcome is the same when I execute the command line in Command Prompt or in a batch file.

Why does insertion of the redirection part (`2> nul`) change the exit code received by the operators `&&` and `||`?

Comment: Using parens changes the behavior `(set VAR) 2>nul &&echo Yes.|| echo No!!` - or - `(set VAR 2>nul) &&echo Yes.|| echo No!!` also no space between `>` and `nul` => `set VAR 2>nul&&echo Yes.||echo No`

Comment: This is the general method of doing what you want: `If Defined VAR (Echo Yes) Else Echo No.`

Comment: @LotPings, thanks! it seems the space between `nul` and `&&` makes the difference. I just found out that `2> nul set VAR && ... || ...` also works as expected; seems there is a space treated as part of the variable name...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to the command line:

```cmd
set VAR 2> nul && echo Yes. || echo No!!
```

It seems that the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> between `nul` and `&&` becomes treated as part of the variable name, so `set` does not check variables whose names begin with `VAR`, but instead `VAR` + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, which is apparently not defined.

---

I created a batch file with a lot of tests, incorporating the cases from the useful [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57778895/conditional-execution-behind-set-var-2-nul-fails#comment101992898_57778895) by user [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411):

```cmd
@echo on
@rem /* Execute test cases in a sub-routine twice,
@rem    once with variable `VAR` defined and once not: */
@for %%I in ("Value" "") do @(
    set "VAR=%%~I"
    echo/& < nul set /P ="VARIABLE: "
    if defined VAR (set VAR) else echo VAR=
    call :SUB
)
@goto :EOF

:SUB
@rem // This constitutes a list of test cases:
@echo/& echo UNQUOTED (VAR):
set VAR && echo Yes. || echo No!!
set VAR> nul && echo Yes. || echo No!!
set VAR > nul && echo Yes. || echo No!!
set VAR 2> nul && echo Yes. || echo No!!
(set VAR > nul) && echo Yes. || echo No!!
(set VAR 2> nul) && echo Yes. || echo No!!
set VAR > nul&& echo Yes. || echo No!!
set VAR 2> nul&& echo Yes. || echo No!!
> nul set VAR && echo Yes. || echo No!!
2> nul set VAR && echo Yes. || echo No!!
@echo/& echo QUOTED ("VAR"):
set "VAR" && echo Yes. || echo No!!
set "VAR"> nul && echo Yes. || echo No!!
set "VAR" > nul && echo Yes. || echo No!!
set "VAR" 2> nul && echo Yes. || echo No!!
(set "VAR" > nul) && echo Yes. || echo No!!
(set "VAR" 2> nul) && echo Yes. || echo No!!
set "VAR" > nul&& echo Yes. || echo No!!
set "VAR" 2> nul&& echo Yes. || echo No!!
> nul set "VAR" && echo Yes. || echo No!!
2> nul set "VAR" && echo Yes. || echo No!!
@goto :EOF
```

And this is the related console window output:

> ```cmd
> >>> test-set.bat
>
> VARIABLE: VAR=Value
>
> UNQUOTED (VAR):
>
> >>> set VAR   && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> VAR=Value
> Yes.
>
> >>> set VAR  1>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> Yes.
>
> >>> set VAR   1>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> Environment variable VAR   not defined
> No!!
>
> >>> set VAR   2>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> No!!
>
> >>> (set VAR  1>nul )  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> Yes.
>
> >>> (set VAR  2>nul )  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> VAR=Value
> Yes.
>
> >>> set VAR  1>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> Yes.
>
> >>> set VAR  2>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> VAR=Value
> Yes.
>
> >>> set VAR  1>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> Yes.
>
> >>> set VAR  2>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> VAR=Value
> Yes.
>
> QUOTED ("VAR"):
>
> >>> set "VAR"   && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> VAR=Value
> Yes.
>
> >>> set "VAR"  1>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> Yes.
>
> >>> set "VAR"   1>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> Yes.
>
> >>> set "VAR"   2>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> VAR=Value
> Yes.
>
> >>> (set "VAR"  1>nul )  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> Yes.
>
> >>> (set "VAR"  2>nul )  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> VAR=Value
> Yes.
>
> >>> set "VAR"  1>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> Yes.
>
> >>> set "VAR"  2>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> VAR=Value
> Yes.
>
> >>> set "VAR"  1>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> Yes.
>
> >>> set "VAR"  2>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> VAR=Value
> Yes.
>
> VARIABLE: VAR=
>
> UNQUOTED (VAR):
>
> >>> set VAR   && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> Environment variable VAR  not defined
> No!!
>
> >>> set VAR  1>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> Environment variable VAR  not defined
> No!!
>
> >>> set VAR   1>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> Environment variable VAR   not defined
> No!!
>
> >>> set VAR   2>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> No!!
>
> >>> (set VAR  1>nul )  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> Environment variable VAR  not defined
> No!!
>
> >>> (set VAR  2>nul )  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> No!!
>
> >>> set VAR  1>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> Environment variable VAR  not defined
> No!!
>
> >>> set VAR  2>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> No!!
>
> >>> set VAR  1>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> Environment variable VAR  not defined
> No!!
>
> >>> set VAR  2>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> No!!
>
> QUOTED ("VAR"):
>
> >>> set "VAR"   && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> Environment variable VAR not defined
> No!!
>
> >>> set "VAR"  1>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> Environment variable VAR not defined
> No!!
>
> >>> set "VAR"   1>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> Environment variable VAR not defined
> No!!
>
> >>> set "VAR"   2>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> No!!
>
> >>> (set "VAR"  1>nul )  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> Environment variable VAR not defined
> No!!
>
> >>> (set "VAR"  2>nul )  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> No!!
>
> >>> set "VAR"  1>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> Environment variable VAR not defined
> No!!
>
> >>> set "VAR"  2>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> No!!
>
> >>> set "VAR"  1>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> Environment variable VAR not defined
> No!!
>
> >>> set "VAR"  2>nul  && echo Yes.   || echo No!!
> No!!
> ```

The only cases that fail are those:

```cmd
set VAR > nul && echo Yes. || echo No!!
set VAR 2> nul && echo Yes. || echo No!!
```

When the command parser recognises and temporarily removes the redirection part (see description of phase 2 in [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133)), potential <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> before `>` and/or after `nul` are left behind, which seem to be treated as part of the variable name by `set`, unless the given variable name is quoted; just one <kbd>SPACE</kbd> in total seems to be tolerated though.

Take also a look at the error messages `Environment variable VAR   not defined` with different numbers of <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> behind the variable name.

---

The `set` command seems to handle its arguments in a particular way:

```cmd
@set "VAR=Value"
rem // No trailing spaces -- returns `VAR=Value`:
set VAR
rem // One trailing space -- returns `VAR=Value`:
set VAR 
rem // Two or more trailing spaces -- returns an ERROR!
set VAR  
rem // No trailing spaces -- returns `VAR=Value`:
set "VAR"
rem // One trailing space -- returns `VAR=Value`!?
set "VAR "
rem // Two or more trailing spaces -- returns an ERROR!
set "VAR  "
```

The unquoted syntax seems not to follow the standard rules for tokenisation where two or more consecutive token separators like the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> become combined into a single one.

The big surprise to me is that even the quoted syntax tolerances one <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, though it ignores all <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> following the closing `"` at least.

Even more surprising is the fact that some other text (like `X`) behind a <kbd>SPACE</kbd> still returns no error:

```cmd
@set "VAR=Value"
rem // No spaces behind `X`, one in front -- returns `VAR=Value`!?
set VAR X
rem // No spaces behind `X`, two in front -- returns an ERROR!
set VAR  X
rem // No spaces behind `X`, one in front -- returns `VAR=Value`!?
set "VAR X"
rem // No spaces behind `X`, two in front -- returns an ERROR!
set "VAR  X"
```

Comment: You could also use `set "var<space>=test"`, then `set VAR 2> nul && echo Yes. || echo No!!` results to YES

Comment: Good idea, @jeb! Seems that `set` handles its arguments particularly, I just tried `set VAR`, followed by one space, which passes (meaning `VAR=Value` is returned), but with more than one, it fails...

Comment: By the way, @jeb, when `VAR` is defined, `set VAR X` (only one space before `X` and none after!) returns `VAR=Value`, most surprisingly...

Comment: You should be aware that `set VAR` command does _NOT_ reset the errorlevel to 0 when `VAR` variable does exists; it just set the errorlevel to 1 when the variable does not exists, unless the batch file have `.cmd` extension as described in **Table 3** of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34987886/778560). It seems that `set VAR` command also manage the "Exit Code" described in the same answer because `set VAR && echo Yes || echo No` construct does _NOT_ change an errorlevel value previously set to 1 or any value even if the construct prints "Yes". @jeb