# implicit "popd" on batch exit

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, pushd

Is there a way to undo all `pushd` at the end of script. What I have is:

```
pushd somwhere
rem doing stuff
goto end

:end
popd
goto :EOF
```

What I'd like to have is:

```
setlocal
pushd somwhere
rem doing stuff
goto :EOF
```

But that doesn't work, the directory stays "pushd". Another try where I can't say how many `pushd` will occur would be:

```
set CurrentDir=%CD%
rem doing a lot of pushd and popd
pushd somwhere

:POPBACK
if /i not "%CD%" == "%CurrentDir%" popd & goto POPBACK
```

But that looks like I can easily get stuck at `:POPBACK`. Adding a counter to exit that loop is a bit uncertain at which dir I end up.

In that context I'd like to know if a can see the stack of pushd directories. The only thing I found was `$+` in `prompt $P$+$G` which adds a '+' for each pushd directory e.g. `D:\CMD++>`. But I can't see a way how to make use of that.

EDIT:
I just noticed there is something wrong with the `$+` of `prompt` that confused me.
The `setlocal` in the example above actually makes the script return to the initial directory, but the prompt shows a '+' indicating a missing `popd`.

```
D:\CMD>test.cmd
D:\CMD>prompt $P$+$g
D:\CMD>setlocal
D:\CMD>pushd e:\DATA
e:\DATA+>goto :EOF
D:\CMD+>popd
D:\CMD>
```

EDIT:
Due to the hint to the difference between local environment and directory stack I expanded the example form above, pushing to C:\DATA before calling the script. the script returns to where it has been called from (C:\DATA). So far so good. The first `popd` shows no effect as it removes the last `pushd` from stack but not changing the directory, since the directory change has been undone by the (implicit) endlocal. The second `popd` returns to initial directory as expected.

```
D:\CMD>pushd C:\DATA
C:\DATA+>d:\cmd\test.cmd
C:\DATA+>prompt $P$+$g
C:\DATA+>setlocal
C:\DATA+>pushd e:\DATA
e:\DATA++>goto :EOF
C:\DATA++>popd
C:\DATA+>popd
D:\CMD>
```

Comment: The easiest way is to simply avoid it and use `cd /D` instead; when you use `setlocal`, the environment is localised, and the current directory is also part of it; localization is always (!) properly ended by an implicit `endlocal`…

Comment: The `pushd` is to use UNC paths. I forgot to write the endlocal, luckily it's implicit  :-).

Comment: Environment localisation and putting directories on the `pushd`/`popd` stack are totally different things, so `endlocal` does unfortunately not at all affect the directory stack…

Comment: I tried that last example with and without `setlocal` ending up either in D:\CMD or in E:\DATA. Right now I'd say it does undo the pushd. But it appears it is not done by a `popd` thus having the remaing '+' at the `prompt`.

Comment: Did you try that in directly Command Prompt? because `setlocal`/`endlocal` has no effect then…

Comment: Not entirly, the `setlocal` and `pusd` are in test.cmd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two points here:

**1. Setlocal/Endlocal commands save/restore current directory!**

This means that when `Endlocal` command is executed, the current directory is returned to the point it has when the previous `Setlocal` command was executed. This happens no matter if the `Endlocal` is explicitly executed, or it is implicitly executed by the termination of the called subroutine (via `exit /B` or `goto :EOF` commands).

This behaviour could be used to solve your problem, because *all changes* of the current directory are reverted when `endlocal` command is executed. That is:

```
setlocal
cd somwhere
rem doing stuff
goto :EOF
```

**However** note that this behavior *is **not** related* to `pushd/popd` commands! You can not mix the use of this feature with `pushd/popd` commands. You would need to complete several tests until the mechanism of the interaction between these two features be comprehended.

This is an undocumented behavior discussed [here](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4436).

---

**2. POPD command sets the Exit Code when there is no previous PUSHD**

As described below **Exit Code management** section at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/what-are-the-errorlevel-values-set-by-internal-cmd-exe-commands/34987886#34987886), there are some commands that does not set the ErrorLevel when an error happens, but sets an internal value we could call "Exit Code". This value can be tested via the `&& ||` construct this way:

```
command && Then command when Exit Code == 0 || Else command when Exit code != 0
```

`POPD` is one of this type of commands (described under **Table 5**), so we could use this feature to execute `POPD` several times until there is not a matching `PUSHD` previously executed:

```
@echo off
setlocal

echo Enter in:
for /L %%i in (1,1,%1) do echo %%i & pushd ..

echo Leave out:
set "n=0"
:nextLevel
popd || goto exitLevels
   set /A n+=1
   echo %n%
   goto nextLevel
:exitLevels

echo Done
```

Bottom line: a simple `popd && goto POPBACK` line solves your problem...

Answer (score 5):

The [`pushd` command](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) without any arguments lists the contents of the directory stack, which can be made use of, by writing the list with [output redirection `>`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) to a (temporary) file, which is then read by a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), and to determine how many [`popd` commands](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) are necessary.

In a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```cmd
pushd > "tempfile.tmp" && (
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%P in ("tempfile.tmp") do popd
    del "tempfile.tmp"
)
```

Directly in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```cmd
pushd > "tempfile.tmp" && (for /F "usebackq delims=" %P in ("tempfile.tmp") do @popd) & del "tempfile.tmp"
```

Note, that you cannot use `for /F "delims=" %P in ('pushd') do ( … )`, because [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) would execute `pushd` in a new instance of [`cmd.exe`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html), which has got its own new `pushd`/`popd` stack.

---

One way to prevent residues from the `pushd`/`popd` stack is to simply avoid `pushd` and to use [`cd /D`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) instead within a localised environment (by [`setlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)/[`endlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html) in a batch file), because, unlike `popd`, `endlocal` becomes implicitly executed whenever necessary (even if the batch file contains wrong syntax that leads to a fatal error that aborts execution, like `rem %~`). This of course only works when there are no UNC paths to be handled (that is, to be mapped to local paths).

---

It is advisable to use `pushd`/`popd` only in a limited code section with out any branches (by `if`, `goto`, etc.). Additionally, ensure to account for potential errors (using [conditional execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) here):

```cmd
rem // First stack level:
pushd "D:\main" && (
    rem // Second stack level:
    pushd "D:\main\sub" && (
        rem /* If `D:\main\sub` does not exist, `pushd` would obviously fail;
        rem    to avoid unintended `popd`, use conditional execution `&&`: */
        popd
    )
    rem // We are still in directory `D:\main` here as expected.
    popd
)
```

Comment: Yes, @Aacini, `popd` indeed sets the exit code (proven by `popd || rem/`, upon which `ErrorLevel` is also set to `1` with an empty stack), which I was not aware of…

Comment: Well, this lack of knowledge cost you 15 rep points... **`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`**  But I gave you 10 to compensate! **`:)`**

Comment: Well, @Aacini, this loss of reputation is absolutely worth the gain of knowledge… `;)`

Comment: @Aacini, off course.. I don't know why I did not focus on the exitcode on windows.. I kept thinking `errorlevel` while I wrote the comment..  I also have a version to post as an Answer.. hold a sec.

Answer (score 0):

After my own reminder of `exit codes` in a now deleted comment and the answer posted by @Aacini, one more version

```
@echo off
pushd "somewhere"
pushd "somewhere else"

:pop
popd && (echo %cd% & goto :pop) || goto :EOF
```

Where `echo %cd%` will only show the each item in the stack, so can be removed and simply become:

```
:pop
popd && goto :pop || goto :EOF
```