# Conditional programming with batch - can't direct STDERR to NUL

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm having a problem with what seems like it should be a fairly basic piece of a script.

```
ECHO !url1! >> !hostsfile! && ECHO Successfully added !url1! to file. || 2>&1>NUL && ECHO Unable to write !url1! to file. && GOTO :FAIL
```

It's a conditional that tries to write a URL to a given file, and if access to that file is denied, prints an error message. Unfortunately, CMD also generates its own error message, so at the moment, as output, I'm getting the default error *"Access denied"* followed by my own *"Unable to write www.url.com to file."*

I've tried without luck to pipe the default error message to NUL, but even with all my reading up on it, my knowledge on how piping works and the syntax for it is still sparse, and I'm not getting anywhere.

**Also, as an aside:** is there any way to split that line to be more manageable without causing errors?

Trying stuff like:

```
ECHO !url1! >> !hostsfile! && ECHO Successfully added !url1! to Hosts file. 
|| 2>&1>NUL && ECHO Unable to write !url1! to Hosts. && GOTO :FAIL
```

or

```
ECHO !url1! >> !hostsfile! && ECHO Successfully added !url1! to Hosts file. || 
2>&1>NUL && ECHO Unable to write !url1! to Hosts. && GOTO :FAIL
```

...results in "unexpected *character*" errors.

**NB. Exclamation marks are being used for variables because of delayed expansion.**

Comment: Echo doesn't return an errorlevel [dbenhams extensive answer to an errorlevel question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34937706/6811411) and read also [ss64.com errorlevel](http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html)

Comment: You should use redirection this way `2>&1 >Nul` or `2>&1 1>Nul` put a space between or explicitly number the standard stream with 1

Comment: @LotPings - So how would I accomplish what I'm trying to do without `echo`? Is there a command I can use to check for write permissions instead? Is there a way I can use `echo` for the purpose that I'm wanting to?

Comment: Also, what's the reason for the space between the streams and the NUL? Is it invalid without it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several issues:

1. `2>&1>NUL` is invalid [redirection syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), you cannot concatenate multiple redirection operators like that. I assume you want to redirect the *STDERR* stream to the `nul` device, so it should read `2>nul` or `2> nul`.
2. You can only redirect the input/output of a command, hence you cannot use redirection without any command. You are trying to (incorrectly) redirect `2>&1>NUL`, but there is no command.
3. The `echo` command does actually not produce the error message `Access is denied.`, it is caused by a failed redirection. Therefore you must enclose the redirected `echo` command in parentheses in order to be able to suppress the error message by the `2> nul` redirection.
4. Note that the `echo` command itself does not set the [`ErrorLevel`](http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) pseudo-variable nor the exit code<sup>1</sup>. However, a failed redirection (`<`, `>`, `>>`) sets the exit code, which is what you are interested in.
5. You need to ensure that the `goto` command is only executed in the `||` branch, so you should put that entire portion in between parentheses.
6. When you write `echo Text > file.ext`, the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> in between `Text` and `>` is also output. To avoid that, either simply remove it like `echo Text>file.ext`, place a pair of parentheses around the `echo` command like `(echo Text) > file.ext`, or revert the syntax like `> file.ext echo Text` (which is the way I prefer as it is the most general one).
7. It is quite similar when you write `echo Text & goto :LABEL`, the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> in front of `&` is output as well. To avoid that, remove it, or enclose the `echo` part within parentheses.
8. In your further attempts you do not tell `cmd` that the two lines belong together. Line continuation is done by ending a line with a caret `^`, so the next one is concatenated<sup>2</sup>. The next line should be preceded by (at least) a <kbd>SPACE</kbd>. Alternatively, parenthesised blocks of code may span multiple lines, so you could also end the first line like `... || (` and have the next line like `... )` for them to be considered as a single command line.

Here is the fixed code:

```bat
(>> "!hostsfile!" echo !url1!) 2> nul && (echo Successfully added !url1! to file.) || (echo Unable to write !url1! to file.& goto :FAIL)
```

Or (using line continuation):

```bat
(>> "!hostsfile!" echo !url1!) 2> nul && (echo Successfully added !url1! to file.) ^
    || ((echo Unable to write !url1! to file.) & goto :FAIL)
```

Or even (using parenthesised blocks):

```bat
(>> "!hostsfile!" echo !url1!) 2> nul && (
    echo Successfully added !url1! to file.
) || (
    echo Unable to write !url1! to file.
    goto :FAIL
)
```

---

<sub>1)  These two values are almost always are the same, but there are rare cases where they differ; the `&&` and `||` operators do actually not care about `ErrorLevel`, they rather use the exit code.</sub>

<sub>2)  The trailing caret `^` lets `cmd` ignore the next line-break *and* escape the following character, so two lines `echo A^` and `& echo B` cause the output `A& echo B` as the `&` appears escaped; to achieve two lines of output `A` and `B`, change the second line to <kbd>SPACE</kbd> + `& echo B`, so the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> is escaped but the ampersand is not.</sub>

Comment: Nice answer for the most part. I ought to point out that it actually is `echo` that's triggering the "Access is denied" messages. If you open a command prompt without escalation and try to append your hosts file, that's the error that results. I didn't test whether the same error occurs if hosts is attrib'd +s or +r, but I suspect it does.  Still, +1.

Comment: Thanks, @rojo! What do you mean by "without escalation"? Not sure whether it is really `echo` producing the error, because `2> nul > "!hostfile!" echo Text` displays the error message, only `2> nul (> "!hostfile!" echo Text)`...

Comment: By "without escalation" I mean not as administrator.  If you're running Windows 10 you'd right-click your Start menu and choose the Command Prompt that doesn't say "(Admin)".

Comment: @rojo, I see; I just recognised that I did not finish my previous sentence: *[...], only `2> nul (> "!hostfile!" echo Text)` suppresses the error message...*

Comment: Great answer aschipfl - Very well written. @rojo - aschipfl is correct, it is not ECHO that triggers the error message, it is the failed redirection. The redirection takes place before any command is executed, and if the redirection fails, the command is never executed, so the command could not possibly trigger the error. I have done extensive testing, and I don't think it is possible for ECHO to return a detectable error. See http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6881 for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you want to redirect stderr to NUL, then just `2>NUL`.  To choke off the stderr of `echo`, you should encapsulate the `echo` statements within an additional generation of parentheses, and redirect `2>NUL` for the entire code block.

And while you're adding parenthetical code blocks, to answer your "as an aside" question, you can pretty much put parentheses before or after any command.  This is useful when writing compound command clauses / conditionals to stick with one command per line and make your code more readable.

Here's an illustration:

```js
@echo off & setlocal

set "hosts=%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"
set "url=169.254.0.1        test"

2>NUL (
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >>"%hosts%" (echo !url!) && (
        echo Successfully added.
        endlocal
    ) || (
        echo Addition failed.  Try running this as administrator.
        exit /b 1
    )
)

exit /b
```

This successfully suppresses any "Access is denied." message, echoing only your specified success or fail message as appropriate.

By the way, I did `(echo !url!)` to avoid echoing the trailing space, and just because I think it's prettier / easier to read than `echo !url!&&`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this:

```
Set hostsfile=%Systemroot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
Findstr /I "!url1!" "!hostsfile!" 2>&1 >NUL &&(Echo !hostsfile! already contains !url1! & goto :whereever)
>> !hostsfile! ECHO !url1! 
Findstr /I "!url1!" "!hostsfile!" 2>&1 >NUL ||(Echo Couldn't add !url1! to !hostsfile! & goto :whereever)
```