# 'RD' command not returning '0' or '1' as errorlevel on success or failure

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, errorlevel, rd

I am using the `RD` command in my batch script to remove a directory.

I assumed `RD` should return `0` for success, or `1` for failure. but it doesn't appear to do so.

I am using the `Robocopy` command utility before the `RD` command, and its taking the `Errorlevel` from `Robocopy` instead.

Please advise the exact exit codes `RD` returns for success and failure.

```bash
robocopy src target ...
rd /S /Q %Target%
IF  %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0  goto :good
IF  %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0  goto :fail
```

Comment: Could you please include the code which defines `%Target%`, and preferably the rest of the `Robocopy`command and the labelled sections `:good` and `:fail`. We should be able to just copy your code onto our machines and run it to reproduce what you have reported.

Comment: You might want to check out [ERRORLEVEL is not %ERRORLEVEL%](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080926-00/?p=20743) from Raymond Chen.

Comment: I recommend opening a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), running `if /?` and reading the output help. There is explained already on first output help page how to evaluate the exit code of a command or program assigned to the __dynamic__ (not __environment__) variable `ERRORLEVEL` which is `if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto fail` or `if NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 goto good`. But better would be `rd /Q /S "%Target%" 2>nul` and `if exist "%Target%\" goto fail` if the environment variable `Target` is defined, for example, with `set "Target=C:\Temp\Development & Test(!),Target 100%"`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `RD` command have a "funny" way to return error codes. Basically, you just need to add `|| REM` command after the `RD` in order to correctly "set" the ERRORLEVEL value *on errors* (the ERRORLEVEL is *not* modified when it works correctly):

```
robocopy src target ...
rd /S /Q %Target% || rem
IF  %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0  goto :good
IF  %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0  goto :fail
```

These are the error values returned by `RD` command this way:

```
1 = Bad switch given
2 = Directory not found
5 = Access denied
32 = Directory in use
145 = Directory not empty.
```

This behavior is described with detail below **Table 5** header at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/what-are-the-errorlevel-values-set-by-internal-cmd-exe-commands/34987886#34987886) about "Errorlevel values set by internal commands"

Comment: I don't quite understand, your linked answer says `rem` doesn't change the error level.  How does adding it to the command change anything?

Comment: @MarkRansom: Did you read the **Table 5 - Commands or features that set the Exit Code** and the explanation above it about **Exit Code management** as I specified in my answer?

Comment: I went back to see if I missed anything, and I still don't see a satisfactory explanation of why it works.  The best I was able to find was https://stackoverflow.com/a/34937706/5987

Comment: @MarkRansom: My linked answer indicate: _"There are two ways to test the ERRORLEVEL value: via IF ERRORLEVEL / IF %ERRORLEVEL% command, or using the command && thenCmd when ERRORLEVEL is 0 || elseCmd when ERRORLEVEL is not 0 construct. However, certain particular commands and redirection errors returns a value that only works in the second case and is not reflected in the ERRORLEVEL; we may call "Exit Code" this value. When this Exit Code is not zero, it can be passed to the ERRORLEVEL executing any command of Table 1 in the elseCmd part."_ and end with the same link you posted...

Comment: @MarkRansom: Now, if you want to know _why_ this work this way? Well, the simplest answer is "because cmd.exe was done this way"... **`:(`**

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is incorrect.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

MD hit
RD hit
ECHO %errorlevel%
RD miss
ECHO %errorlevel%

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: This code returns `0` for both `RD hit` and `RD miss` in my Windows 10...

Comment: @Aacini As they do on my windows 11, hence OP's claim "I assumed RD should return 0 for success, or 1 for failure." is incorrect. Good info about `||REM`...

Comment: Ah, ok. You just confirmed _the problem_ described by the OP...