# Windows executable that does nothing

Tags: windows

Suppose I'm working in a system that wants to execute *something* in a workflow step, but I want it to do nothing instead.

Unlike the slightly-related question [Dummy command in windows cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190536/dummy-command-in-windows-cmd), I'm not in any sort of shell (that I'm aware of).  I can only point to an executable and provide parameters.

Is there anything in a typical Windows installation that can be executed as a do-nothing placeholder and returns 0 as its exit code?

I could install a dummy script, but I'd rather avoid doing that to maintain some portability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /D /C ""
```

If there's no shell, then `%SYSTEMROOT%` is likely not available.  For a typical, out-of-the-box installation, the above path is expected.  Otherwise, customize to fit your environment.

From the help text:

```
/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
. . .
/D      Disable execution of AutoRun commands from registry (see below)
```

Following up `/C` with `""` executes nothing.  Invoking `/D` prevents any default scripts from running.

Finally, this returns 0, so it won't interrupt the workflow.